# Any Visual Studio Programs are not letting me code

Tags: c#

This started happening lately, every I use a piece of code it counts it as wrong.

for example:

Lets say I want to make a socket

```
public class PacketReader
{

Socket MainSocket;

MainSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP);                               // acts like MainSocket was never declared

    // Bind the socket to the selected IP address
    MainSocket.Bind(newIPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(cmbInterfaces.Text),0));

    // Set the socket options
    MainSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP,  //Applies only to IP packets
                       SocketOptionName.HeaderIncluded, //Set the include header
                       true);                           //option to true

    byte[] byTrue = newbyte[4]{1, 0, 0, 0};
    byte[] byOut = newbyte[4];

    //Socket.IOControl is analogous to the WSAIoctl method of Winsock 2
    MainSocket.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll,  //SIO_RCVALL of Winsock
                 byTrue, byOut);

    //Start receiving the packets asynchronously
    MainSocket.BeginReceive(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None,
                    newAsyncCallback(OnReceive), null);
}
```

then when I try to use it in a function or some part of the class, it returns it as "Name is a field but its used as a type". I have no idea how I am using it as a type when all I'm doing is declaring it in the class.

So My question is, How do I prevent this from happening. I need to find a solution quick or I am going to fail an project I have due in a month because of this stupid problem.

Comment: Can you post more code?

Comment: Please post your code, especially the line that triggers `Name is a field but is used as a type`.

Comment: That sounds like a name-spacing conflict. Please provide code.

Comment: Alright, I changed it, I still dont get why its  doing that though.

Comment: No, the OP clearly has no understanding of the structure of a program. That's clear even if he posts no code.

Comment: assign it in the same line or move the assignment inside some method(like the ctor for example) as i bet MainSocket is a class member variable...

Comment: Do you put this code inside a function?

Comment: I do have an understanding Of code, the code it self has no understanding of what I'm trying to do. Please refrain from making unnecessary comments.

Comment: I cannot even put this code in a new line without it making a fuss. I know not why it does this. Because Up to about a week ago, VS 2012 was working fine.

Comment: Where are you declaring and initializing this, and where are you trying to call it from?  I'm thinking it might be a scope issue, though I'd expect a different error/warning.

Comment: Yes, I tried many times, I even attempted to install VS 2013 RC, and that did not solve it either.

Comment: @Blaze: Then I doubt it is an issue with the IDE, and rather your code. Would you mind posting the entire code in your file?

Comment: I'm gonna guess and say that the bracing in your file is completely screwed. Invalid bracing causes all sorts of random errors because the compiler cannot figure out what scope is where. Post your entire file here.

Comment: Entire file, meaning: Everything in the file.. not just what you want to chop out of it. Clearly something is broken.. short snippets won't help here.

Comment: no blaze....all....even to the last curly whirly.....as simon could very be on the spot.

Comment: This is how it exactly is inside the IDE. with red error markings though, I'll attempt to uninstall it once again, but I' not going to place my hopes so high.

Comment: if that is all then my answer was an improvement but you need more....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code isn't in a method.

You cannot declare a variable and assign it separately within the class scope. You also cannot put random expressions in class scope. Change your code to this:

```
public class PacketReader
{
    Socket MainSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP);

    public PacketReader() {
        // rest of the code here in your constructor
    }
}
```

This is going to sound mean.. but if you are unaware of basic language structure rules like this... then a packet monitor may just be out of your reach.

Comment: Thanks...I do know the basics, The thing is back in VS 2010, I did not have to do something like this, which was odd. I just wrote the code and It functioned normally. I guess 2012 changed that.

Comment: This is not a matter of 2010 vs. 2012. This is a basic language rule that has been around since the inception of C# (and other C-style languages).

Comment: @Blaze: Not at all... Methods have always been a fundamental part of programming. Nothing changed with a new IDE, the C# specification has remained the same as far as this topic goes.

Comment: Are you sure? odd, The way you see it above is how it worked in VS 2010, then it magically stopped working when I changed the version. But Anyways, Thanks, Even though I know this method in C++, I guess I completely Ignored that fact that it suppose to be the same for C# and Other languages.

Comment: @Blaze: you are simply mistaken. Regular code has never been allowed outside methods in C#. Ever. Period. End of story.

Comment: @siride No need to be so rude, I'm beginning to think that this place is not met to help people who need it. It starting to look like a playground of programming As***les. So again, No need to be rude, I was just making a statement to clarify something.

Comment: @Blaze I think you, like everyone else, read text in your own way. I don't think siride was trying to be rude, just stating facts. Nevertheless, keep at it - and make sure you continue to ask specific programming questions here. SO is invaluable for people starting out, as long as they read the FAQ and how to ask a question properly.

Answer (score 1):

You must put your code in a method to run it! You can only declare variables outside the method scope. Any statements that need to be run must be within a method. Not trying to be rude, but I suggest you learn a bit more before you attempt something like this. Check out this [methods tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_methods.htm) for more information.

```
public class PacketReader
{
    Socket MainSocket;

    public static void Main()
    {
        MainSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP);                               // acts like MainSocket was never declared

        // Bind the socket to the selected IP address
        MainSocket.Bind(newIPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(cmbInterfaces.Text),0));

        // Set the socket options
        MainSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP,  //Applies only to IP packets
                           SocketOptionName.HeaderIncluded, //Set the include header
                           true);                           //option to true

        byte[] byTrue = newbyte[4]{1, 0, 0, 0};
        byte[] byOut = newbyte[4];

        //Socket.IOControl is analogous to the WSAIoctl method of Winsock 2
        MainSocket.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll,  //SIO_RCVALL of Winsock
                     byTrue, byOut);

        //Start receiving the packets asynchronously
        MainSocket.BeginReceive(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None,
                    newAsyncCallback(OnReceive), null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing something like this:

```
Public class YourClass
{
   Socket MainSocket;

   MainSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP);

   //other members and methods and so on...
}
```

Do this for example...

```
Public class YourClass
{
   Socket MainSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP);

   //other members and methods and so on...
}
```

then if you want the rest you could (depending on your design and goal)place it in the constructor or methods......

Comment: How is your second code snippet better or different than the first?  I would expect either way to work.

Comment: I attempted that as well, but when i try to call the socket, it gives me the same error.

Comment: then i will remove my answer because was mostly to attempt to have a better understanding of your situation...

Comment: @Tim: You cannot assign a variable or use other statements after the variable has been created in the class scope.